# MySql Join - How to get all rows besides related? HowTo SUM within a Joined Table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 Tables (with prefix "pindex_")

```
names       photos          link
id, name    id, filename    photo_id, name_id
--------    ------------    -----------------
1 , leo     1 , aa.jpg      1       , 1
2 , liz     2 , bb.jpg 
3 , ann
```

So Leo is connected to Photo aa.jpg
Now I would like to get all names that are not connected to aa.jpg.
Result should be: Liz (2), Ann (3).

I have tried with this but it isn't working so far:

```
select nm.name from pindex_names nm
join pindex_link pl on pl.name_id = nm.id
join pindex_photos pp on pl.photo_id = pp.id
where pl.name_id !='$id'
```

And my second question is how i can SUM up a Col within a joined table?
For exaple I would like to Count how many names are connected to a certain photo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select n.*
from names n
where not exists (select 1
                  from link l join
                       photos p
                       on l.photo_id = p.id
                  where l.name_id = n.id and
                        p.filename = 'aa.jpg'
                 );
```

Comment: THX! That worked fine, can you give me a hint how i can Count how many names are connected with a certain filename?

Comment: @user2987790 . . . In the context of this question, the answer is 0, because that is the premise -- the names don't have that filename.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM pindex_names
WHERE id NOT IN
(
   SELECT name_id 
   FROM pindex_link pl
   INNER JOIN pindex_photos pp 
      ON pl.photo_id = pp.id 
   WHERE filename='aa.jpg'
)
```

Comment: mysql returns empty result, and where do i specify the filename (or id of table pindex_photos)?